# Protect a table against concurrent data changes while allowing to vacuum it

Tags: postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL 9.5. In a transaction, I check if data in the table satisfy some conditions:

```
IF condition1 THEN
  -- do this
ELSE
  IF condition2 THEN
    -- do that
  ELSE
    ...
  END IF;
END IF;
```

Since data in the table may change between the IFs, I want to protect the table against concurrent data changes before checking the condition1. The minimal table lock mode that protects data against concurrent modification is `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE`. However, it also prevents the table from being vacuumed and, worst of all, any vacuum (or even autovacuum) process prevents me from locking the table and checking the conditions.

I am not in control of queries that modify the table, so I cannot use advisory locks. The transaction isolation level is `READ COMMITTED`. Also, I would prefer not to use triggers.

What are possible solutions?

Comment: I don't think a vacuum (except `VACUUM FREEZE` maybe) stops you from modifying your table, even less from checking the conditions.

Comment: Of course, they do not stop me from modifying the table or checking the conditions. The problem is that at the moment of checking conditon2 I want to guarantee that the table has not changed since the time when condition1 was checked.

Comment: Are you checking the physical contents of the table?  Because your visible data won't change by vacuuming.  Or I don't understand something in your problem ;)

Comment: Vacuuming does not change the content, but I cannot lock the table in the `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` mode if the table is being vacuumed.

Comment: Why do you worry about vacuum? How long are you planning to hold those locks? Unless you intend to hold them for many hours you don't need to worry

Comment: Because the table is huge and it takes hours to autovacuum it. Every time the autovacuum process is running the code above just hangs trying to lock the table in the `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` mode.